Typing in Google Docs
I am filling out a form that was sent to me in Google Docs.  There are lines on the form that I need to type above.  The line separates when I type, moving the line apart. How am I able to type above the line?

The line was likely created using underscore (_) characters. In this case, you can't write over the line. Depending on the font used, you might need to delete one underscore character for each character you enter or a few less.
You might apply the underline style to make the text look like they were written over the line. There is an option on the Edit menu, a button on the Google Docs toolbar, and a keyboard shortcut, too. If you can't find them, click the magnifying glass on the toolbar or the Help menu. An option to search the menus will be shown; the exact option name might vary, but it should be something like "Search the menus". Click it, then type "underline"

Thank you so much, Ruben.  I so appreciate your help!  Mary

@MaryP You are very welcome. Please click the tick mark near the up/down buttons to mark this answer as accepted. For details, see What should I do when someone answers my question
